# Solving $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{ 5^x-3^x}{x}$ without L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

The question is

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{ 5^x-3^x}{x}$$

Unfortunately, we cannot use *L'Hôpital's rule* to solve this limit, so I'm not sure how to proceed with the question.

I'm sure there is an elegant way to manipulate the algebra to resolve the indeterminate form, however I just can't find it. Any help would be much appreciated thanks again.

Comment: You can try writing using the Taylor series expansion on $5^{x}$ and $3^{x}$.

Answer (score 7):

Remember the fundamental limits $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{a^x -1}{x} = \ln(a)$.

Then write $\frac{5^x - 3^x}{x} = \frac{5^x - 1}{x} - \frac{3^x -1}{x}$.

So you have that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{5^x - 1}{x} - \frac{3^x -1}{x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{5^x - 1}{x} - \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{3^x - 1}{x} = \ln(5) - \ln(3) = \ln(\frac{5}{3}) $

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the most general case of $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{ a^x-b^x}{x}$$ $$\frac{ a^x-b^x}{x}=\frac{ e^{x \log(a)}- e^{x \log(b)}}{x} $$ For any value of $t$ we have $$e^t=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!}$$ So, replace $t$ by $x\log(a)$ and later by $x\log(b)$. This makes $$a^x-b^x=\left(1+x \log (a)+\frac{1}{2} x^2 \log ^2(a)+O\left(x^3\right) \right)-\left(1+x \log (b)+\frac{1}{2} x^2 \log ^2(b)+O\left(x^3\right) \right)$$ $$a^x-b^x=x (\log (a)-\log (b))+\frac{1}{2} x^2 \left(\log ^2(a)-\log
   ^2(b)\right)+O\left(x^3\right)$$ $$\frac{ a^x-b^x}{x}=(\log (a)-\log (b))+\frac{1}{2} x \left(\log ^2(a)-\log
   ^2(b)\right)+O\left(x^2\right)$$ 
$$\frac{ a^x-b^x}{x}=\log \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)\left(1+\log(\sqrt{ab})x\right)+O\left(x^2\right)$$ 
which shows the limit and also how it is approached when $x\to 0$.